# Call Main activity from a Fragment of viewPager

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, native

How to limit my main activity to not go back on the last page of my Fragment once return from the last page of Fragment to Main activity like I have One Home activity and that home activity leads to 3 more activities on clicking the button and in which one activity has fragments. The last page of the fragment is leading to home activity but when I back pressed on the home activity it again leads me to the last page of a fragment from where I've come and then I press the back button again then my application shuts

MY MAIN ACTIVITY CLASS

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
    }


    public void Consultation_Form(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConsultationForm.class));
        finish();
    }

    public void Registration_Form(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegistrationForm.class));
        finish();

    }

    public void Assessment_Form(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AssessmentForn.class));
        finish();

    }

    public void Booking_Form(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookingForm.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

MY FRAGMENT CLASS OF VIEWPAGER

```
public class PC_v16 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pc_v16, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvReferral);
        Button btBackHome = view.findViewById(R.id.btBackHome);

        btBackHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `finish` your Viewpager Activity before moving to Home Activity.

In  your Fragment
Change this

```
 btBackHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

To

```
btBackHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Home.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().finish();
    }
});
```